How to change text weight after pausing in beamer?
I want to highlight a particular text in a list after all the text has appeared. So for example, I want the slides in this order:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize} 
\item this is text 1
\pause
\item this is text 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{this is text 1}
\item this is text 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Is there a way this can be done in the same slide instead of creating two separate slides?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{boldenv}{\only{\bfseries}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-|bold@3> this is text 1
\item<2-> this is text 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



I made an edit to my question. I basically want to show both bullet points and then highlight the first point without erasing the second point.

@thewizard See my updated answer

Do you want something like this?
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize} 
    \item<.-| alert@3> \textbf<3>{this is text 1}
    \pause
    \item this is text 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

You could also use overlay specifications rather than \pause. For example
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize} 
    \item<+-| alert@3> \textbf<3>{this is text 1}
    \item<+-> this is text 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

produces the same output as the code above.
